# Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have problem with the src. I need to use id number from API in order to show on my website the image. when i do it, it shows me an error in the terminal 'Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.'

```js
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';


import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { IState } from '../../reducers';
import { IUsersPhotos } from '../../reducers/usersPhotos';


const ProfileImg = styled.img`
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
`


const ProfileImage = () => {

    // const { usersList } = useSelector<IState, IUsersReducer>(globalState => globalState.users);
    const { usersPhotos } = useSelector<IState, IUsersPhotos>(globalState => globalState.photos);


    return( 
        <Link to="/profilePage" style={{textDecoration: 'none'}}>
        <ProfileImg src= {usersPhotos?.[0]?.id} />
        </Link>  
    )
}



export default ProfileImage;
```

Comment: the `ProfileImg` components property `src` only accepts values with type `string` or `undefined` (default). You cant pass it a number - just as an error say. If `ProfileImg` is your own created component - add a type `number` to the list of supported types. Or run `toString` the `usersPhotos?.[0]?.id` so the `id` remains a number but you pass it as a string so the component is happy. Regardless - u cant force a different property type then allowed.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should change your type to represent the data type `number`?

It's hard to say without seeing your type. This should do:

```
type IUsersPhotos {
 data: {
  id?: number | string
 }
}
```